# 'form-group' + (valid ? '' : ${errorClass})

Tags: thymeleaf

```
<th:block th:fragment="input (label, labelClass, fieldName, type, errorClass, outerDivClass, inputClass)">
    <div th:with="valid=${!#fields.hasErrors(fieldName)}"
         th:class="${'form-group' + (valid ? '' : ${errorClass})}"
         class="form-group">

         ...

    </div>
</th:block>
```

**Stacktrace**

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "'form-group' + (valid ? '' : ${errorClass})" (template: "general/fragments/inputField" - line 3, col 10)
```

How can I cope with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You have nested `${...}` variables. So, just remove the inner `${` and `}` - the ones surrounding the `errorClass` variable name.

Here is your example, but using a `<div>` for ease of testing:

```html
<div th:class="${'form-group' + (valid ? '' : errorClass)}"></div>
```

Another way to implement this is as follows:

```html
<div th:class="'form-group' + (${valid} ? '' : ${errorClass})"></div>
```

In this case, we have each variable surrounded by its own `${` and `}` - but, again, there is no nesting of `${...}` values.